# How do I conditionally use a Perl module only if I'm on Windows?

Tags: perl, module

The following Perl code ..

```
if ($^O eq "MSWin32") {
  use Win32;                                                                                                                                                                                           
  .. do windows specific stuff ..
}
```

.. works under Windows, but fails to run under all other platforms ("Can't locate Win32.pm in @INC"). How do I instruct Perl to try import Win32 only when running under Windows, and ignore the import statement under all other platform?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I conditionally use a module in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945583/how-can-i-conditionally-use-a-module-in-perl)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This code will work in all situations, and also performs the load at compile-time, as other modules you are building might depend on it:

```
BEGIN {
    if ($^O eq "MSWin32")
    {
        require Module;
        Module->import();  # assuming you would not be passing arguments to "use Module"
    }
}
```

This is because `use Module (qw(foo bar))` is equivalent to `BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( qw(foo bar) ); }` as described in [perldoc -f use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html).

(EDIT, a few years later...)

This is even better though:

```
use if $^O eq "MSWin32", Module;
```

Read more about the `if` pragma [here](http://metacpan.org/module/if).

Comment: *`Bareword "Module" not allowed while "strict subs" in use ...`* - it looked so good from a distance....

Comment: @jww You are supposed to replace "Module" by the actual module name you want to load. And that namespace needs to be declared in the file with a `package` statement.

Comment: Oh got it, thanks. Why did you not use `Win32`? (I'm not a seasoned Perl veteran, so I often need to look up basic Perl).

Answer (score 11):

As a shortcut for the sequence:

```
BEGIN {
    if ($^O eq "MSWin32")
    {
        require Win32;
        Win32::->import();  # or ...->import( your-args ); if you passed import arguments to use Win32
    }
}
```

you can use the if pragma:

```
use if $^O eq "MSWin32", "Win32";  # or ..."Win32", your-args;
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, `use Module` or `use Module LIST` are evaluated at compile time no matter where they appear in the code. The runtime equivalent is

```
require Module;
Module->import(LIST)
```

Answer (score 1):

`require Module;`

But `use` also calls `import`, `require` does not.  So, if the module exports to the default namespace, you should also call

`import Module qw(stuff_to_import)`;

You can also `eval "use Module"` - which works great IF perl can find the proper path at runtime.

Comment: Do not use indirect method calls, they are not Best Practices by a long shot. Do `Module->import(qw(stuff));` instead.