# How can I conditionally use a module in Perl?

Tags: perl, module, include, conditional-statements

I want to do something like this in Perl:

```
$Module1="ReportHashFile1"; # ReportHashFile1.pm
$Module2="ReportHashFile2"; # ReportHashFile2.pm

if(Condition1)
{
  use $Module1;
}
elsif(Condition2)
{
  use $Module2;
}
```

ReportHashFile*.pm contains a package ReportHashFile* .

Also how to reference an array inside module based on dynamic module name?

```
@Array= @$Module1::Array_inside_module;
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this. Some sort of compiler directive?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You might find the [`if`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?if) module useful for this.

Otherwise the basic idea is to use `require`, which happens at run-time, instead of `use`, which happens at compile-time. Note that '

```
BEGIN {
    my $module = $condition ? $Module1 : $Module2;
    my $file = $module;
    $file =~ s[::][/]g;
    $file .= '.pm';
    require $file;
    $module->import;
}
```

As for addressing globals, it might be easier if you just exported the variable or a function returning it to the caller, which you could use by its unqualified name. Otherwise there's also the possibility of using a method and calling it as `$Module->method_name`.

Alternatively, you could use symbolic references as documented in `perlref`. However, that's usually quite a code smell.

```
my @array = do {
    no strict 'refs';
    @{ ${ "${Module}::Array_inside_module" } };
};
```

Comment: +1 for addressing "How do I call a method with the same name from whichever module I loaded" :)

Comment: I usually throw an eval in there in case you can't load the module. I like to shut things down nicely instead of seeing that awful dump of @INC that perl spits out. :)

Answer (score 12):

Unless the execution speed is important, you can use string [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

```
if (Condition1) {
    eval "use $Module1"; die $@ if $@;
}
elsif (Condition2) {
    eval "use $Module2"; die $@ if $@;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

People have already told you how you can load the module with Perl primitives. There's also [Module::Load::Conditional](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Load-Conditional).

If you're looking to access an array of the same name no matter which module you loaded, consider making a method for that so you can skip the symbolic reference stuff. Give each module a method of the same name:

```
package ReportHashFileFoo;
our @some_package_variable;
sub get_array { \@some_package_variable }
```

Then, when you load that module:

```
if( ... some condition ... ) {
    eval "use $module" or croak ...;
    my $array_ref = $module->get_array;
    }
```

**2023 update** Lately I've been using `require` in a `state` expression since that only happens once in the scope:

```
use v5.10;

if( ... some condition ... ) {
    state $rc =  require $module;
    my $array_ref = $module->get_array;
    }
```

I don't know what you're really doing ([XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)), but there's probably a better design. When things seem tricky like this, it's usually because you're overlooking a better way to to it.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe helpful...

A little example for debugging.

```pl
sub DEBUG () {1};               # It's the condition (may be a debuglevel...)

use if DEBUG, Data::Dumper;     # Conditionally load

my $testvar = "foo";
print "Testing: $testvar\n" if     DEBUG;
print "No testing\n"        unless DEBUG;

print Dumper \$testvar if DEBUG;  # "Dumper" only available if "DEBUG" returns "true".
```

Output with `sub DEBUG () {1};`

```txt
Testing: foo
$VAR1 = \'foo';
```

Output with `sub DEBUG () {0};`

```txt
No testing
```

q.v.
[perldoc.perl.org/if](https://perldoc.perl.org/if)