# How to include conditionally Perl modules and libraries, as well as Global variables from them

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am developing a Perl script. Inside I use various moudules:

```
use Module::One;
use Module::Two;
...
```

I also use global variables from these modules:

```
$GLOBAL_1 = 1;
$GLOBAL_2 = 1;
...
```

Let's say that the name of the script is

```
my_script.pl
```

Is it possible to include the above-mentioned modules and globals conditionally when passing to the script an argument called 'no_libs', but whenever not passing this argument - not include or use them? 
Something like that:

```
perl my_cript.pl no_libs

if ( $ARGV[0] eq 'no_libs' ) {
    use Module::One;
    use Module::Two;
    ...

    $GLOBAL_1 = 1;
    $GLOBAL_2 = 1;
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is [if](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?if), but conditionally loading module that export makes no sense. Conditionally loading modules that export vars (and trying to use those vars) is right out. (Exporting vars is bad enough in normal circumstances.)

Comment: @ikegami I thought `if` went at compile time ...?

Comment: @zdim, The "if" is a link to the "if" module (not the `if` statement).

Comment: @zdim, Oh, sorry, thought you were referring to the `if` statement which executes at runtime. Yes, `use if ...` is exectued at compile-time. That's when modules should be loaded, so that's why it's a good way to do it.

Comment: @ikegami Ah, OK.  (How else would `use` be conditioned?)  I took their condition to imply runtime (assuming more complex command line processing), even though as it stands it doesn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I conditionally use a module in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945583/how-can-i-conditionally-use-a-module-in-perl)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect that the example `$ARGV[0] eq '...'` really stands for more involved processing of the command line arguments, including assignments to variables and such. Then that happens at runtime and you cannot condition `use` that way, as it runs at compile time.

The example as stated works at compile time though, in which case use the [if pragma](https://metacpan.org/pod/if)

```
use if @ARGV && ($ARGV[0] eq 'no_libs'), "Module::One", qw(...);
```

which has the same effect as `use Module::One qw(...)` if the condition is true.

If the decision indeed happens at runtime then you need to use [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) instead

```
if ($no_libs) {
    require Module::One;
    Module::One->import( qw(f1 f2) );  # as in: use Module::One qw(f1 f2);
    ...
}
```

The [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) comes down to `require` since `use Module LIST;` means exactly

> `BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }`

so you are doing practically the same but at runtime.

However, global variables can't be imported this way since `strict` won't have their declarations in time.  Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for the comment. You can use them directly as `$Module::One::Var`, for `our $Var` in `Module::One`, but please see the following comments.

In general, exporting global variables from modules is not a good practice as it erodes the overall design, by entangling supposedly distinct components and bypassing their interfaces. It may also lead to subtle and hard to detect problems.

Having globals *conditionally* seems strange: how do you use them if they may not exist? This can be a confusing design, which can probably be changed.